# Forming numbers from a given word

Tags: word-problem

How many integers can you form using the letters of the word "*interchangeability*"? Note: You can ignore spaces when forming numbers.

Comment: What counts as a number, exactly? Do e and i count? What about g, the gravitational constant?

Comment: Sure let's include those too.

Comment: Okay, then *what counts exactly*? There are lots of debatable things I could make - you need to precisely define what would count, or the puzzle has no objective answers.

Comment: You are right, it was too loose. I changed it to integers only.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle; it is simply a rote exercise.  There is no intuitive leap required; no "figuring out".  Anyone with a bit of time on their hands is guaranteed to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eleven numbers: three, eight, nine, ten, thirteen, thirty, thirty-nine, eighty, eighty-nine, ninety, ninety-eight.

Comment: Very well done my friend!